# ReentrantLock's trylock method not allowing turn taking of multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I was studying `MultiThreading` concepts. I came across `ReentrantLock`. It has methods `lock` and `trylock`. As I studied them further, I understood that they can be used instead of `synchronized` keyword block or method. So I tried them again with classic example of `AccountDanger` given in Kathie Sierra book. I observed that `lock` method DO allow turn taking with other threads. But `trylock` boolean method NOT allow turn taking with other threads. example below:

**with `lock` method**

```
package p1;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class AccountDanger implements Runnable {
    private Account account  = new Account();
    private int amt = 10;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Object obj = new Object();
    public void run(){

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            lock.lock();
            try{
                if(account.getBalance()>=amt){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is going to withdraw..");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    account.withdraw(amt);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" has withdrawn. Balance left is : "+account.getBalance());
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("not enough balance for "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        if(account.getBalance()<0){
            System.out.println("account is over withdrawn!!!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        AccountDanger ad = new AccountDanger();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ad,"Mark");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ad,"Phew");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("final balance left is : "+ad.account.getBalance());
    }
}
```

above code with `lock` method allowing both `Mark` and `Phew` threads to take turns.

**with `trylock` method**

```
package p1;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class AccountDanger implements Runnable {
    private Account account  = new Account();
    private int amt = 10;
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Object obj = new Object();
    public void run(){

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            try{
            if(lock.tryLock()){
            if(account.getBalance()>=amt){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is going to withdraw..");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                account.withdraw(amt);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" has withdrawn. Balance left is : "+account.getBalance());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("not enough balance for "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
            }
            }
            finally {
                if(lock.tryLock()){
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
            if(account.getBalance()<0){
                System.out.println("account is over withdrawn!!!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        AccountDanger ad = new AccountDanger();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ad,"Mark");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(ad,"Phew");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("final balance left is : "+ad.account.getBalance());
    }
}
```

above code does NOT allowing `Phew` thread to take turns even when `Thread.sleep()` method is called.

**Account class**

```
package p1;

public class Account{
    private int balance = 100;

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }


    public void withdraw(int amount){
        this.balance = this.balance - amount;
    }
}
```

although both methods are, no doubt, preventing balance to get negative. But I don't understand that why is `trylock` being so serious about the process that it does not allow other thread to come in between the execution even when `Thread.sleep` is called within. Even if I use `lock.unlock` statement in `finally` block after catch block of  `Thread.sleep`, then also only `mark` thread is executing.

Comment: "I don't understand that why is trylock being so serious about the process that it does not allow other thread to come in between the execution even when Thread.sleep is called within" you mean, why does the obtained `Lock` prevent other threads from entering? That's its whole point.

Comment: ok, does that mean that if trylock has achieved a lock it would not release it unless unlock is called in finally

Comment: Yes, `trylock` is equivalent to `lock` except that it doesn't block (ie it returns immediately if the lock cannot be obtained).

Comment: however if I add finally block adjacent to thread.sleeps catch block with unlock method in it, then also `phew` thread not enter in there

Comment: That's because the thread passed the `trylock` without obtaining the lock, and since it won't try again it won't notice that it's released eventually.

Comment: ok, do you mean, that if `phew` thread returned out having false for `trylock`, it won't come again.. If that is so, then I understood. please confirm.

Comment: Well it does come again (10 times due to the loop), but since it can't obtain the lock every time, the loop will have finished and the *phew` thread terminated before the other thread's `sleep`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162961/discussion-between-jsk-and-daniu).

Comment: @JSK in you finally block you used if (lock.tryLock()) that if succesfull increment the lock count for your thread, therefore if the first lock.tryLock() was succesfull, you'll never unlock it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic misunderstanding was that `trylock` did not aquire a lock, which it does; as I stated in my comment, `trylock` is equivalent to `lock` except it doesn't block if the lock cannot be obtained.

What's happening in your case is this:

1. the Mark thread is started and obtains the lock, then goes to sleep for 0.,5 seconds.
2. in this time, the Phew thread is started. It tries to obtain the lock but fails because Mark has it.
3. the next loop iteration is started for Phew; Phew tries to obtain the lock again and fails. This happens the 10 times the loop is run.
4. the loop finishes; this exits the thread's `run` method and terminated the Phew thread.
5. the Mark thread's sleep finishes.
6. the finally block releases the lock.
7. the next loop iteration is started for Mark. It tries to obtain the lock and succeeds (there's no one else around to obtain the lock anymore). Again, this happens a total of 10 times.

Comment: now understood completely with above steps you explained. Actually I also forgot that lock never released even when sleep is called. Thank you sir, you worked hard to explain me. Multithreading is always so complex. Always need a guru like you for resolving that complex thread structure..